# Changing github credentials

Tags: git

I am a collaborater : my github account name is dave
I am also the repo owner : my github username is chief

I have managed to fork one of chief's projects,
commit and submit a pull request to him.

Now I need to accept that pull request.

How do I switch to chief's credentials, so that I can clone chief/projectname.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When cloning etc, GitHub determines what user you are by your [SSH key](http://help.github.com/troubleshooting-ssh/). I'm not sure you can really do this sensibly without doing one of the following:

- Changing your key from one used for the 'dave' account to one used for the 'chief' account
- Using a different user on your local machine (or a different machine) which has an SSH key for the 'chief' account

However for the exact scenario you describe, you should be able to use GitHub's [fork queue](http://github.com/blog/270-the-fork-queue). That way, you only need to log into github as chief and you should have the options right there in the UI for doing it without having to pull anything down and merge yourself.

Hope that helps.